# Passing "Alias" to functions in C++

Tags: c++, templates, parameter-passing

How to pass something like this to a function

```
using PIN1 = GpioOutputB1;
using PIN2 = GpioOutputB2;
using PIN3 = GpioOutputB3;
using PIN4 = GpioOutputB4;
using PIN5 = GpioOutputB5;
```

passing these `PIN1`, `PIN2` ... etc to a function like this.

```
static void initilize() {
PINx::setOutput();
}
```

Sorry that I am not including the original code for official reasons but the problem is similar.

Comment: You probably want an array of function pointers instead.

Comment: Do you want to pass a list of types to a function, or just one at a time?

Comment: I wanted just one at a time, I was confused with templates because of how to pass Alias, I will try the suggestions and keep you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about as template parameter?

```
template <typename PINx>
static void initilize () {
   PINx::setOutput();
}
```

En passant: I suppose that `setOutput()` is a **`static`** method.

Given that (in this example) `PINx` can't be deduced, you have to call `initialize()` explicitly passing the type

```
initialize<PIN3>();
```

Take also in count that you can also call the function using the original type

```
initialize<GpioOutputB3>();
```